# Proving convergence of sequence of functions of sequence

Tags: calculus, sequence-of-function

> Consider the sequence of functions $f_k :A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $\{f_k\} \rightarrow f$ uniformly in A and $f_k$ is continuous in A $\forall k$.  Prove that if $x_0 \in A$ and $\{x_k \}$ is a sequence of points of $A$ such that $\{x_k \} \rightarrow x_0$, then $\{f_k(x_k) \} \rightarrow f(x_0)$.

This is what i' ve done so far:

I have already proven that if a sequence $f_k$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ and $f_k$ are continuous $\forall k$, then $f$ is continuous.

Since $f_k \rightarrow f$ uniformly, given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$, $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for any x, so if we consider the sequence $\{x_k \} \rightarrow x_0$, $|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon$ for all $x_i \in \{x_k \}$  so $\lim_{i\to \infty} |f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)|=|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$. But this would only prove that $\{f_k(x_0) \} \rightarrow f(x_0)$, which is not what I' m trying to prove...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Write

$|f_k(x_k)-f(x_0)|=|f_k(x_k)-f(x_k)+f(x_k)-f(x_0)| \leq |f_k(x_k)-f(x_k)|+|f(x_k)-f(x_0)|$

$\leq \sup_{x \in A}|f_k(x)-f(x)|+ |f(x_k)-f(x_0)|.$

Comment: You are choosing which $n_k$ so that for all $k > n_k$, $|f_k(x_k)-f_k(x_0)| < \epsilon$?

Comment: Oops in my rush i made a mistake , i should have add and substract $f(x_k)$ instead of $f_k(x_{0})$ , am so sorry , i hope i didnt cause any incovenience! I edit it now

Comment: I see, so you're using the result that the uniform limit $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes , exactly am not sure if there is other way .